# Check if sum of a list is equal to either of two values or not

Tags: python, list

I have a list of True or False. I want to know if all of them are either True or False.

My code:

```
list1 = [False, True,False,False,True]
list2 = [False, True,False,True]
list3 = [False, False,False]
list4 = [True, True,True, True,True]

if sum(list1)==len(list1)|0:
    print("Yes! all are either True or False")
else:
    print("Not satisfied")
```

Looks like my code works fine if all are True but not if all are False. How to check if all are False

Expected output for four lists:

```
list1 >> Not satisfied
list2 >> Not satisfied
list3 >> Yes! all are either True or False
list4 >> Yes! all are either True or False
```

Comment: `if sum(list1) in (0, len(list1)):`

Comment: `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, `list4`... can you use a multidimensional list? It's going to be really awkward to work with the lists otherwise. Also, check out `all()` from builtins.

Comment: `if set(list1) in [{True}, {False}]: ...`

Comment: `if len(set(list1)) == 1`…

Comment: @ggorlen I assume that code is just to make it a simple, testable example for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Shouldn't `not any(l) or all(l)` work?

Comment: Just because no one said and for completeness, your approach didn't work because `|` is the **bitwise** or operator. So basically you are just checking if `sum(list1) == len(list1)` (because anything or-ed with 0 is itself) which is the condition for all `True`. What you meant was probably `if sum(list1)==len(list1) or sum(list1)==0:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you could use the built-in `all()` and `any()`:

```
for lst in [list1, list2, list3, list4]:
    if all(lst) or not any(lst):   # if it isn't true that any are true, then all must be False
        print("Yes! all are either True or False")
    else:
        print("Not satisfied")
```

output:

```
Not satisfied
Not satisfied
Yes! all are either True or False
Yes! all are either True or False
```